# Install of Ubuntu 15.04 hanging at "ACPI PCC probe failed" and then "failed command: Read Fpdma Queued"

Tags: system-installation, 15.04, acpi

I have seen many people have this problem during installation, but nobody has fixed this issue.

It occurs during first time installation of 15.04. I am getting `ACPI PCC probe failed` and then `failed command: Read Fpdma Queued` during installation

How should I proceed?

Comment: For anybody reading this some time in the future, the issue has been Solved!

My DVD drive was plugged into a Sata port on my motherboard that did not support ATAPI so the installation was freezing when that functionality was called on (or something like that).
I simply moved the DVD drive to a supported Sata port.

Answer (score 2):

For anybody reading this some time in the future, the issue has been Solved! My DVD drive was plugged into a Sata port on my motherboard that did not support ATAPI so the installation was freezing when that functionality was called on (or something like that). I simply moved the DVD drive to a supported Sata port.