# Have updates to version 15.04 brought some ATAPI usage with them?

Tags: boot, 15.04

I'm apologizing in advance for might be not too clear question's title, I'll try to explain better.

In short, I've started to experience some boot problems, which sometimes result only in longer boot time and sometimes completely prevent the system to load. In the latter case I'm able to see these messages on the screen (and many more):

```
ata3.00: failed command: IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE
ata3.00: cmd a1/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 0 pio 512 is
         res 58/00:02:00:00:02/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x52 (ATA bus error)
ata3.00: status: ( DRDY DRQ )
```

******** skipped here *******

```
INFO: task systemd-udevd:422 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
      Not tainted 3.19.0-20-generic #30-Ubuntu
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

There are already some questions on AskUbuntu about problems like mine:

[Boot failure: failed: command IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228927/boot-failure-failed-command-identify-packet-device)

[Can I prevent an IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE command to a specific device at boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230396/can-i-prevent-an-identify-packet-device-command-to-a-specific-device-at-boot)

[Install of Ubuntu 15.04 hanging at “ACPI PCC probe failed” and then “failed command: Read Fpdma Queued”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630021/install-of-ubuntu-15-04-hanging-at-acpi-pcc-probe-failed-and-then-failed-comm)

what I've understood from these is that either my CD-ROM or some controller on the motherboard does not support ATAPI commands and Ubuntu sends them to the device.

But I assembled my computer in 2012 and have not experienced any problems like the current ones.

So I wonder whether this usage of ATAPI was introduced recently (may be 2 to 3 month ago), because, as I can remember, these problems started after some large updates a couple of month ago.

Because if the answer is "no" then something has broken either in my motherboard or CD-ROM.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO, at least, the problem had no relation to the recent updates of Ubuntu 15.04.

In one of answers at AskUbuntu for similar problem, which I cannot find now, someone mentioned that the lens of a CD-ROM may need cleaning.

I removed the cover of my CD-ROM, and though I doubt that the dust was the cause of the problem, because there was no dust inside and lens seemed clear, but for some reason, after I cleaned the lens with a soft napkin and reconnected the device to the desktop, the drive began to work correctly (before this I was unable to write), and these messages have gone.

I hope, this can be helpful to someone, who might find himself in a problem like mine.